# Верхний индекс текста в SVG

Tags: html, svg

Есть схема помещения в формате svg, встроенная в html-документ. У каждого помещения должна быть надпись, содержащая его площадь в квадратных метрах. Понятно, что  в svg-шном  работать не будет.
Вопрос: Есть ли способ написать м^2 с верхним индексом в svg?

```
<text x="300" y="80" class="square">2376 кв. м. (132х18)</text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сдвинуть текст по вертикали, относительно базовой линии, с помощью SVG-атрибута `baseline-shift` (для *inline*-записи) или одноимённого CSS-свойства (для назначения через стили и классы).

*(Сведения о поддержке браузерами этого свойства везде разнятся.)*

```css
.sup { font-size: .7em; baseline-shift: super; }
.sub { font-size: .7em; baseline-shift: sub; }
```

```html
<svg>
  <text x="10" y="25" class="square">2376 м<tspan baseline-shift="super" font-size=".7em">2</tspan> (132&times;18)</text>
  <text x="10" y="50">H<tspan baseline-shift="sub" font-size=".7em">2</tspan>O</text>
</svg>

<svg>
  <text x="10" y="25" class="square">2376 м<tspan class="sup">2</tspan> (132&times;18)</text>
  <text x="10" y="50">H<tspan class="sub">2</tspan>O</text>
</svg>
```

*Также рекомендую использовать `&times;` (×) вместо различных `х`.*